# How to receive GPRS data and view it on a webpage?

Tags: server

How to receive GPRS data and view it on a webpage?

I am doing a GPRS Datalogger. It sends Data of some sensors to a web server using GPRS. I want to be able to view this data on a webpage in a browser say Google Chrome. Also I need the data which is received by server to be stored in a database. How should I proceed with the designing of Front end for my application? Should I use HTML 5, PHP and MySQL? Is there an example code which receives data from GPRS and shows it on a webpage?

Comment: Your question is too broad and confusing. What do you mean by GPRS data?  Where are you stuck?  I don't see. You taking about Spatial data anywhere. I don't see how this falls within the scope of this site. Please provide more details to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pseudo PHP code for the data logger, it receives the temps values using a GET parameter let us call it "t", and the GPS "x" and "y" and save them  on a mysql database table called TEMPS_LOGS along with the timestamp. The table has four columns (Temp_val(double), x , y and timestamp).

```
  <?php
    //datalogger.php
    $t = $_GET['t'];
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    $y = $_GET['y'];

     $con=mysqli_connect("yourserver","hussein","abc123","my_db");

    //saves the temp and location with timestamp;
    $mysql_query ($con, "INSERT INTO TEMPS_LOGS VALUES ({$t}, {$x}, {$y}, NOW())");


    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

and this is how to call the datalogger.php page

```
http://yourwebserver/datalogger.php?t=17&x=6473643.43&y=2682923
```

Fetching the logs from the database is even easier. We won't need any parameters

```
    <?php
    //fetchlogs.php


     $con=mysqli_connect("yourserver","hussein","abc123","my_db");

    $res = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM TEMPS_LOGS");
    //printing HTML table of the logs
    echo "<table><tr><th>Temp</th><th>X</th><th>Y</th><th>Timestamp</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
      echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td><td>{$row[1]}</td><td>{$row[2]}</td><td>{$row[3]}</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

This is how you can call this page.

```
http://yourwebserver/fetchlogs.php
```

Again, this is just pseudo code, you got to do some changes for it to work. But sure it will give you the idea on how to store and retrieve data using a Web server. Any smart phone is now equipped with 3G/4G connection that will help you get connected to the Internet. Not necessary GPRS

How that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience there is no problem to complete this task. However, I am afraid I need to know what the data logger provides you, i.e. what type of data you try to collect. Dependent on the data type, e.g. location data, or any other sensor data, you might need to use different front ends to display data. For example, for geographical data, you can use SharpMap (C# based control library) for map displaying. You can integrate with other display controls to display real-time sensor data stream. For GPRS, what you need to do are to design and code several communication classes (e.g. TCP/IP, UDP) to connect data logger wirelessly, obtain data remotely and parse data at server side. You can use open-source based database (e.g. PostgreSQL/PostGIS) to store the data, with little software cost.

Comment: Hi, The sensors are temperature sensors and 3 channels of ADC are used for 3 phase system voltage measurement. The datalogger controls some devices and a generator automatically and sends data to web server when an event occurs like power failure etc.... I need to see this data on a web page. This should be an option to store past data (history). If I want to see what events occured on a particular date then the data should be shown on a web page in browser.